# How to create input tag in a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How do i make an input tag inside a div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <script>
            var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
            x.setAttribute("type", "text");
            document.body.appendChild(x);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div>
           Test
       </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

how can i add the input tag to the div

Comment: Your script needs to exist after the elements, or in an event handler that delays the execution, such as on load or whatever the native ready event is.  After that you just need to target the div to append to it, rather than the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to somehow identify that specific `div` amongst all of your `div`s (potentially many). You could do that in many ways, possibly most common: giving the `div` element a `class` attribute and/or an `id` attribute, like so:

- `<div class="name-of-the-class"></div>`
- `<div id="name-of-the-id"></div>`

Let's assume you chose to assign a class to the `div` in which you want to insert an `input` element. Then your div code would look something like this:

```
<div class="test-class">
    Test
</div>
```

Now we can ask ourselves: where do we want to put our `input` element? Do we want to do it in the document's body directly as this line suggests `document.body.appendChild(x);`? 
No, we want to put it in the `div`, which is in the document's body.

We can do that by first finding the `div` (which we can now identify with no problems) and then appending our element to it:

```
document.body.querySelector(".test-class").appendChild(x);
```

---

Unfortunately, that is not everything that needs to be fixed in your code. Since javascript and html are being interpreted line by line, from top to bottom, when your script is executing, the chosen `div` element is not yet created!

We can easily fix that by moving the script at the bottom of our html body. That way, everything we put on our page will be visible if we need to manipulate it with javascript. The complete solution would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="test-class">
           Test
       </div>

       <script>
           var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
           x.setAttribute("type", "text");
           document.body.querySelector(".test-class").appendChild(x);
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your target div has an ID of e.g. `target`, you can use `document.createElement` like so:

```
var div = document.getElementById("target");
var input = document.createElement("input");

//setting the input's properties, e.g.:
input.type="text";
input.name="my_input";

//adding the input to the div
div.appendChild(input);
```

**Note:** For `getElementById` to work, you will need to put your script either at the end of the file, or wrap it in an `onload` event, e.g.:

```
onload = function() {
  //insert code here
}
```

Comment: @PriyanshuGhosh yes, and if you want, you can use a class name instead of an ID. Basically, you need any selector that can "find" your target div.

Comment: @Taplar thanks for pointing out, yes, this should not be in an inline script at the top of the HTML file..